# Plotting different parts of different lists of data

Tags: plotting

Suppose I have the following data:

```
x = Range[15];
y1 = N[RandomInteger[100, 15]/100];
y2 =  N[RandomInteger[100, 15]/100];
y3 =  N[RandomInteger[100, 15]/100];
```

Now, I wish to plot values 1 to 5 of x against values 1 to 5 of y1, values 6 to 10 of x against 6 to 10 of y2, and values 11 to 15 of x against 11 to 15 of y3. Moreover, I wish to show the plots on the same chart, showing the entire range of x.

How is that done? Note that the range of 5 data points at a time was just an example. The ranges in my actual problem are varied, but never overlapping.

Answer (score 3):

```
x = Range[15];
y1 = N[RandomInteger[100, 15]/100];
y2 = N[RandomInteger[100, 15]/100];
y3 = N[RandomInteger[100, 15]/100];

ListLinePlot[{
  Transpose[{x, y1}][[1 ;; 5]],
  Transpose[{x, y2}][[6 ;; 10]],
  Transpose[{x, y3}][[11 ;; 15]]
  }]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this work for you?

```
x = Range[15];
y1 = N[RandomInteger[100, 15]/100];
y2 = N[RandomInteger[100, 15]/100];
y3 = N[RandomInteger[100, 15]/100];
cutoffs = {1, 5, 6, 10, 11, 15};
ListLinePlot[
  Table[
    {x, y1, y2, y3}\[Transpose][[cutoffs[[2 i - 1]] ;; cutoffs[[2 i]], {1, i + 1}]], 
    {i, 3}
  ]
]
```

[image: Plot of multiple functions of x.]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`TemporalData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemporalData.html) as follows:

```
intervals = {{1, 5}, {6, 10}, {11, 15}};
td = TemporalData[{y1, y2, y3}, {x}];
parts = MapIndexed[td["Part", #2[[1]], #] &, intervals];
ListLinePlot[parts, GridLines -> {Flatten @ intervals, None}, Filling -> Bottom]
```

[image]

```
intervals2 = {{1, 6}, {3, 12}, {7, 15}};
ListLinePlot[MapIndexed[td["Part", #2[[1]], #] &, intervals2], 
 Filling -> {1 -> Bottom , 2 -> 1, 3 -> Bottom}, 
 GridLines -> {Flatten @ intervals2, None}]
```

[image]